# Url for oneDrive download file not accepting AccessToken

Tags: ios, objective-c, onedrive

I am trying to make a download url for oneDrive REST API

```
NSString *downloadUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/%@/content?suppress_redirects=true?access_token=%@",
                                 [file objectForKey:@"id"],
                                 [ApiManager sharedInstance].liveClient.session.accessToken
                                 ];
```

Here is my code,
however its giving me error that access token is not found. If i remove suppress redirects it works and generates a url to download. However i want to skip this redirect url.

The query is explained in here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659726.aspx

How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second ? to an & and it should work. I'd also suggest taking a look at the new API (http://dev.onedrive.com) as it's more likely to get new features going forward.